# Google Chrome messed icons and fonts

Tags: google-chrome, icons, fonts

Strange things happen to my Google Chrome (35.0.1916.114) in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

**Before**

[image: my chrome before]

**After**

[image: my chrome after]

As you can see icons and fonts are different and also tab styles changed. Sometimes after system start fonts all over Ubuntu are different. Restart usually solves desktop fonts, but Chrome (and also Chromium) are still messed.

I also noted Chrome's "indicator" icon in toolbar.

I am using standard Google repository (http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/).

Can anyone please help me how to solve this?

Comment: Fonts outside Chrome appears only once and maybe it was because of another system update. I think this question is therefore duplicate and should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! This mess is not a bug, it's feature :) Google Chrome since version 35 updates it's GUI from GTK to Aura. See http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/google-chrome-stable-35-for-linux.html for more informations.